# Setting up Resource bundles in a Maven project Spring MVC (4.1.6)

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, netbeans-7

I am using Netbeans 7 and Maven project using Spring MVC framework. I am trying to access the messages stored in messages.properties under src/main/resources but getting the below error:

> ResourceBundle [classpath:\resources\resources\messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name classpath:\resources\resources\messages, locale en_US

I have the following configuration inside dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:\resources\messages" />
</bean>
```

I also tried to place the properties file under WEB-INF, src/java/package, also tried changing the path but nothing worked.

Please help me fixing the issue.

Comment: Try to use <property name="basename" value="classpath:*/resources/messages" />

Comment: I tried it. But no help. The application cannot find the properties file.

Comment: Ok, I would request you to place on classpath first, so do <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />. It should work and then try to place it in any other folder, don't give resources name

Comment: Actually maven is not copying the resources folder to the web/target/classes folder. I copied the properties file to that folder and now application can find it. Thank you @pashtika for your help.